# Spring Boot Restcontroller as inner class in unit test (webmvctest)

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, inner-classes

Is it somehow possible to declare a RestController in a test context, preferably as a inner class of a spring boot test? I do need it for a specific test setup. I already did try following simple example as a POC:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.AutoConfigureWebClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(ExampleTest.TestController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWebClient
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions = this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/test"));
        resultActions
                .andDo(print());
    }

    @RestController
    public static class TestController {
        @GetMapping("/test")
        public String test() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }

}
```

Testing the endpoint via MockMvc delivers 404 though. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, `TestController` is not loaded to the application context. It could be solved by adding

> @ContextConfiguration(classes= ExampleTest.TestController.class)

The test will look like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(ExampleTest.TestController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= ExampleTest.TestController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWebClient
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions = this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/test"));
        resultActions
                .andDo(print());
    }

    @RestController
    public static class TestController {
        @GetMapping("/test")
        public String test() {
            return "hello";
        }
    }

}
```

And the output:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"5"]
     Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             Body = hello
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks a bunch! Had to add a few config classes to ContextConfiguration though (when using it) for my specific test setup regarding spring security, but thats another story.